# Replace text on image with Pillow

Tags: python, ocr

let us suppose we have following image

[image]

in order to read this text, we can simple use following code :

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text =pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('text_image.png'))
```

i decided  to replace Text with  new Text like this :

```
text =text.replace("Text","new Text")
print(text)
```

result is :

```
Write new Text on Image
using OpenCV
```

now i have place to replace  original text with this text on image, i found following tutorial :
[Replace text with new text](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pillow-writing-text-on-image/)

but  if we  use this command :

```
d1.text((65, 10), "Sample text", fill =(255, 0, 0),font=myFont)
```

we can  see that  there author is using only two coordinate, but our text i think needs rectangle  area right?please  give me hint how to  implement it :

Comment: All that will do is write your text on TOP of what is already there.  You can't simply "replace" text on an image, because there is no way to know exactly what was underneath the text.   If you can predict the background, then you can draw a rectangle to erase the text and then draw your text, but if it's a photo, the best you can do is interpolate.

Comment: can we get  coordinate  of the text?  rectange coordinates?

Comment: Have you checked any of the documentation?  There is an `image_to_boxes` method that should do that.

Comment: then we can use those coordinates right to  overwrite with text right?

Comment: Yes, but that's not going to erase the text that's already there.  Your text will be scribbled over the top, mixed in.